# how CFRunLoop Change the order of execution

Tags: ios, objective-c, runloop

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("oneQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL), ^
    {
        [self syncAction];
    });
//    CFRunLoopRun();     //  1
    NSLog(@"mainQueue execut 1");
}

- (void)syncAction
{
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
//        CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
        NSLog(@"mainQueue execut 2");   // 2
    });
}
```

If I commented `CFRunLoopRun();`  and `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());`

output:

```
mainQueue execut 1
mainQueue execut 2
```

but if I not comment `CFRunLoopRun();` and `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());`

output:

```
mainQueue execut 2
mainQueue execut 1
```

I always think,if `viewDidLoad` not excute complation, the `mainQueue` will not execute
    new function block,but why `CFRunLoopRun` can make `mainQueue` execute skip current function 
and execute new block which added later by other `asyncQueue`. 
    and when `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurren))`,`viewDidLoad` continue execute .
    what `CFRunLoop` done?